# why is the long ParNew GC with very high user time only?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm running a Java app in container (with k8s), and found a long STW gc:

```
2019-07-10T16:45:31.081+0800: 1620992.943: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-07-10T16:45:31.082+0800: 1620992.944: [ParNew: 1232340K->105476K(1258304K), 0.0558525 secs] 1412255K->290236K(4054528K), 0.0571538 secs] [Times: user=0.23 sys=0.20, real=0.06 secs] 
2019-07-10T16:46:08.906+0800: 1621030.767: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-07-10T16:46:08.907+0800: 1621030.768: [ParNew: 1224004K->97149K(1258304K), 5.4008859 secs] 1408764K->286575K(4054528K), 5.4022113 secs] [Times: user=37.65 sys=0.00, real=5.41 secs] 
2019-07-10T16:46:48.426+0800: 1621070.287: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-07-10T16:46:48.426+0800: 1621070.288: [ParNew: 1215677K->106022K(1258304K), 0.0545431 secs] 1405103K->300294K(4054528K), 0.0557196 secs] [Times: user=0.41 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
```

The second GC reclaimed almost the same amount of memory (1.1GB) compared to its previous and next GC, while cost significant amount of time (5.4 seconds). Which is related to the very high user time in the ParNew GC.

I've Googled around it, only to find most of the blogs and stackoverflow answers are dealing with large sys time and real time, which does not concern my problem.

My Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

And GC threads from jstack are:

```
"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be809b000 nid=0xb5 runnable 
"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be801d000 nid=0xab runnable 
"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be801f000 nid=0xac runnable 
"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8020800 nid=0xad runnable 
"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8022800 nid=0xae runnable 
"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8024800 nid=0xaf runnable 
"Gang worker#5 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8026000 nid=0xb0 runnable 
"Gang worker#6 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8028000 nid=0xb1 runnable 
"Gang worker#7 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be802a000 nid=0xb2 runnable 
"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be812d800 nid=0xb9 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"Gang worker#0 (Parallel CMS Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8097000 nid=0xb3 runnable 
"Gang worker#1 (Parallel CMS Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3be8099000 nid=0xb4 runnable
```

Comment: `1.8.0_102-b14` - you may want to upgrade, that's a 3 year old build.

Answer (score 1):

Real time is wall time, i.e. how much time actually passed. User time is the CPU cycles aggregated over all cores spent in userspace, doing work. Since you have 8 parallel GC threads it just means most of those 5 seconds were spent on most of the cores doing collection work.

That in itself does not tell us anything about why it took that much time. To my knowledge there is not much that can be done to get more information out of ParNew, it's a very simple collector. You could switch to G1 which provides far more detailed logs.

[Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's minor GC](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html) by Alexey Ragozin has a breakdown of ParNew timespend.

You may also want to monitor your system for CPU/IO/Swap contention (e.g. by logging /proc/pressure/* with timestamps in current linux kernels may be of use) that could slow down the activity of the garbage collector.